# Elastic Search - weighting base on an attribute

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in Elastic Search to weight results base on an attribute other than the one used for the search query. For example, we search the field 'name', but all documents that have 'with_pictures' attributed to true weighted higher.

Comment: did u get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from u :)

Comment: thank u for accepting the answer :) It would be great if you can upvote my answer as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) on individual fields, that will be boosted automatically — count more towards the relevance score — at query time, with the boost parameter

Adding working example with index data, mapping and search query

**Index mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "with_pictures": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "boost": 2 
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
    "name": "A",
    "with_pictures": false
}

{
    "name": "A",
    "with_pictures": true
}
{
    "name": "B",
    "with_pictures": true
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [

              {
                "term": {
                  "name": "A"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "with_pictures": true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.4100108,
        "_source": {
          "name": "A",
          "with_pictures": true
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "name": "B",
          "with_pictures": true
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "fd_cb1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.4700036,
        "_source": {
          "name": "A",
          "with_pictures": false
        }
      }
    ]
```

Score of documents satisfying both the conditions of `name` and `with_properties` is having the highest score. But the document having `name: B` and `with_pictures: true` have higher score than `name: A` and `with_pictures: false`( because of the boost applied on the `with_pictures`

You can also refer [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) that allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query.